# += operator on a pair and make_pair with templates

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I came across the following while reading codebase of a library.

`errorMap`, used in the below code is defined as:

```cpp
map <const string, pair<int, double>> errorMap;
```

And the relevant part of the code being:

```cpp
errorMap["substitutions"] += make_pair<int,double>(targetLength, substitutions);
errorMap["insertions"] += make_pair<int,double>(targetLength, insertions);
errorMap["deletions"] += make_pair<int,double>(targetLength, deletions);
```

The above part is throwing [this](https://ptpb.pw/hBf6) compilation error. When running the library through it's own build system, the code seems to be compiling. Can someone shed some light on what exactly is happening here?

PS: I already looked at the pair documentation at cppreference and other sites, none of them specify a `+=` operator for a pair. This is the first time I'm encountering a `make_pair` with templated arguments, on which I can't find more information either.

Comment: Maybe they defined their own operator +=?

Comment: Unlikely, unless it's possible to overload pair<int, double>'s += operator. Is that possible?

Comment: I think the error is because `make_pair` uses perfect forwarding, which only works when it deduces the type. By specifying the types, it'll only accept rvalues. I don't know why the error would go away.

Comment: @immibis is correct. I found the += operator in a source file. It is possible to overload a pair's +=, that's new information to me. Thank you. It's just an addition of the corresponding values. Must've lost the header file while switching build systems.

Comment: += has nothing to do with your error. You've hit one of those rare cases of C++11 breaking C++98 code.

Comment: The `make_pair` deduction still fails, though.

Comment: @n.m: I understand. There were two parts to my question, how the += came and how make_pair with templating works.

Any idea how I can fix this? Would setting compiler flags to C++98 do?
Edit: Setting flags worked, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not about the pair, it's about the map. The [`operator []`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) is used to insert or update elements in a map.

For example in a `std::map<char, int> myMap{{'a', 27}, {'b', 3}, {'c', 1}};`, I could do the following (as demonstrated in the page linked above):

```
myMap['a'] = 6; //to change the value associated to 'a'
myMap['d'] = 8; //to insert a new value
```

I could also do the following:

```
myMap['b'] += 9; //Now the value associated to b is 3 + 9 = 12
```

In the 3 lines of code posted in the question, the values associated with the strings inside of the brackets are being updated.

The `operator+=` have probably been overloaded for pairs with template. (Look at the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21956119/add-stdpair-with-operator)) This might be why, you're getting those errors instead of the following (replace char with string):

```
error: no match for ‘operator+=’ (operand types are ‘std::map<char, std::pair<int, double> >::mapped_type {aka std::pair<int, double>}’ and ‘std::pair<int, double>’)
```

Since the same operation doesn't reproduce the same errors, the poblem is from deeper implementations, for which you provided no context. They might be related to right and left values:

```
cannot convert ‘targetLength’ (type ‘int’) to type ‘int&&’
```

You [*might*][1] want to look at those [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27806504/cannot-convert-a-type-int-to-type-double#27806710) for that.

[1]: *Might because I'm not sure of what I'm saying. I wanted to contribute with a comment, but not enough rep, so I tried my best with an answer.*

Comment: Thanks, the answers you've linked are quite helpful. The query got answered in comments. It was a c++98 thing, and I was compiling with c++11. It compiled successfully after.